# how to combine these 2 jquery code into one

Tags: jquery, xhtml

Should work same as it's working independently.

This

```
(function($) { 
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#number1').hide();
        $('.button1').click(function(){
              $('.table1').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon"); 
                return false;
   });
});

})(jQuery);
```

and this

```
(function($) { 
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#number2').hide();
        $('.button2').click(function(){
              $('.table2').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon"); 
                return false;
   });
});

})(jQuery);
```

both will be used on same page.

**Thanks**

**Edit: Added after @Felix comment**

@Felix - Do you mean like this?

```
(function($) { 
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#number2, #number1').hide();
        $('.button2').click(function(){
              $('.table2').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon"); 
                return false;
   });
});
        $('.button1').click(function(){
              $('.table1').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon");
                return false;
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Seriously? Just copy the content from the one `$(document).ready` to the other. Then you can improve the code by writing `$('#number1, #number2').hide();`

Comment: `$('#number1, #number2').hide()` this is ok but what about other part? can we combine `.button` also in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample HTML

```
<button id="button1" class="btn" div="table1">Table 1</button>
<button id="button2" class="btn" div="table2">Table 2</button>
<div class="myDiv" id="div1"><table><tr><td>Table1</td></tr></table></div>
<div class="myDiv" id="div2"><table><tr><td>Table2</td></tr></table></div>
```

CSS

```
  .myDiv { display:none; }
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btn').click(function(){
        //identify same class to all your div for example in this case I will define all tables as myDiv
        // doing this will not fix the effect to just two tables
        $(".myDiv").slideUp(); //Hide all divs first

        $('#'+$(this).attr("div")).slideToggle(); //show the required
        $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I also applied the suggestion of @Felix Kling

Comment: @metal gear solid, to combine both click function, you need to identify them by one fixed class and then pass the table name as attribute somewhere in you `buttons`

See the update

Comment: @Strax - I have 2 link and 2 table on same page. and default i want to keep both table hidden . and if user will click on link "table1" then table1 should expand and when user will clik on link "table2" then table1 should be hidden and table1 should expand.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid, you mispelled my name. But the answer is still the same, it will slide all the tables and show the tables you want later. May be you need accordion check this http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Comment: @Starx - sorry, I have `table` inside `div`

Comment: That's your script, use the one I provided

Comment: I noticed you didn't see the UPDATED portion of my answer so here is your solution http://jsbin.com/isopa. And I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: your example is working now. but , see my 2nd comment of your answer "I have `table` inside `div`"

Comment: @metal-gear-solid, this is a basic HTML dude, wrap the table in a div. See my answer again , I will modify it

Comment: `div` is not a valid attribute on a button HTML element. I would not introduce custom attributes.

Comment: @Felix kling, you are right, and I agree that one should avoid this as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($) { 
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#number1, #number2').hide();

        $('.button1, .button2').click(function(){
            if($(this).is('.button1')) {
                $('.table1').slideToggle();
            else
                $('.table2').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon"); 
            return false;
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thanks - and i also need if i clicked on table1 first then if i click on table2 then table1 should be hidden and table1 should expand

Comment: @Starx, you answer is close but you the call to `$($(this).attr("table")).slideToggle();` will not work it should be `$('.'+$(this).attr("table")).slideToggle();` since table1 and table2 are classes not tags

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you have 2 repetitive markups, which should have same behavior.
In that case, I would extract JS code, which defines required behavior, and call it with required markup arguments:

```
(function($) { 
    function CondfigureEvents(numberSelector, buttonSelector, tableSelector)
    {
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(numberSelector).hide();
        $(buttonSelector).click(function(){
            $(tableSelector).slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon"); 
            return false;
        });
    }
    CondfigureEvents('#number1', '.button1', '.table1');
    CondfigureEvents('#number2', '.button2', '.table2');
});
})(jQuery);
```